Next js application deployment issue with static/chunks
Whenever I deploy my next.js application each page is not reflecting the changes and sometimes when I refresh the page is getting crashed. It is working fine on local even on 'npm run build' and 'npm start' Any solution for this!
This is the content is showing
//next.config.mjs
const const nextConfig = {
  async rewrites() {
    return [
      {
        source: "/dashboard",
        destination: "/pages/dashboard",
      },
      {
        source: "/connectors",
        destination: "/pages/connectors",
      },
      {
        source: "/all-investigations",
        destination: "/pages/all-investigations",
      },
      {
        source: "/my-investigations",
        destination: "/pages/all-investigations",
      },
      {
        source: "/investigation-details",
        destination: "/pages/investigation-details/[id]",
      },
      {
        source: "/add-ai-coworker",
        destination: "/pages/add-ai-coworker",
      },
      {
        source: "/agent",
        destination: "/pages/agent",
      },
      {
        source: "/my-dashboard",
        destination: "/pages/dashboard",
      },
      {
        source: "/agent-details",
        destination: "/pages/agent-details/[id]",
      },
      {
        source: "/signup",
        destination: "/auth/signup",
      },
      {
        source: "/",
        destination: "/auth/signin",
      },
      // Add more rewrite rules as necessary
    ];
  },
  // experimental: {
  //   optimizeCss: true,
  // },
  // transpilePackages: ["@acme/ui", "lodash-es"],
  // compiler: {
  //   styledComponents: true,
  // },
};
export default nextConfig;

//package.json
{
  "name": "frontend",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev --turbo",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start",
    "lint": "next lint",
    "test": "jest",
    "test:watch": "jest --watch"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@aws-amplify/adapter-nextjs": "^1.2.6",
    "@microsoft/fetch-event-source": "^2.0.1",
    "@radix-ui/react-accordion": "^1.1.2",
    "@radix-ui/react-checkbox": "^1.0.4",
    "@radix-ui/react-icons": "^1.3.0",
    "@radix-ui/react-progress": "^1.0.3",
    "@radix-ui/react-switch": "^1.0.3",
    "@radix-ui/themes": "^3.0.3",
    "@reduxjs/toolkit": "^2.2.3",
    "aws-amplify": "^6.3.8",
    "axios": "^1.6.8",
    "chart.js": "^4.4.3",
    "critters": "^0.0.24",
    "install": "^0.13.0",
    "js-cookie": "^3.0.5",
    "latest": "^0.2.0",
    "next": "^14.2.5",
    "npm": "^10.8.0",
    "radix-ui": "^1.0.1",
    "react": "^18",
    "react-chartjs-2": "^5.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18",
    "react-icons": "^5.0.1",
    "react-json-tree": "^0.19.0",
    "react-redux": "^9.1.1",
    "react-syntax-highlighter": "^15.5.0",
    "react-toastify": "^10.0.5",
    "reactflow": "^11.11.1",
    "redux-persist": "^6.0.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.24.4",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^6.4.2",
    "@testing-library/react": "^15.0.2",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^14.5.2",
    "@types/jest": "^29.5.12",
    "@types/js-cookie": "^3.0.6",
    "@types/node": "20.12.7",
    "@types/react": "18.2.79",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18",
    "@types/react-syntax-highlighter": "^15.5.13",
    "autoprefixer": "^10.0.1",
    "babel-jest": "^29.7.0",
    "eslint": "^8",
    "eslint-config-next": "14.1.4",
    "generate-react-cli": "^8.4.1",
    "jest": "^29.7.0",
    "jest-environment-jsdom": "^29.7.0",
    "postcss": "^8",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.3.0",
    "ts-jest": "^29.1.2",
    "ts-node": "^10.9.2",
    "typescript": "5.4.5"
  }
}

I have tried adding different configuration from doc. Mainly I am using app routing in my application. I am deploying with amazon aws using ubuntu server with tmux.
